# Better Way to Post Info in DB?

Tags: php, database, insert

Currently, my code on the HTML side looks like this:

```
<form action="newstory.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="author" value="<?php echo $loggedInUser->display_username; ?>"
/>
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $loggedInUser->user_id ?>" />
Story Title: <input type="text" name="story_name" /><br>
Story: <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="story" /></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here's the PHP side:

```
include("dbconnect.php");

mysql_select_db("scratch", $con);

$author     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
$author_id  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
$story_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['story_name']);
$story      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['story']);

$sql= "
INSERT INTO stories (author, author_id, story_name, story)
VALUES ('$author', '$author_id','$story_name', '$story')
";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Story Submitted! Redirecting to Homepage...";
//User is shown this for about 3 seconds
header('Refresh: 3; URL=index.php');

mysql_close($con)
```

I want to get rid of the

```
<input type="hidden" name="author" value="<?php echo $loggedInUser->display_username; ?
>"/>
```

Since people could easily edit that and post as any user, but I'm unsure of a good way. Same goes for userid.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: If the user is logged in, use a session to store his ID and insert that into the database.

Comment: Look up PDO and don't use mysql_* functions while you're at it.

Comment: Don't send userdata in forms.. Use `$_SESSION` data for authentication

Answer (score 1):

Sending the `userid` via a hidden input field in a form is a HUGE security threat. Anybody can change that value with e.g. Chrome's inspector or FireBug. When someone log's in; you must store at least their user_id in a session. You can also store more info in the session so that you don't have to query the database on every request to e.g. show the logged-in user's username somewhere on the page.

I don't know how you handle log-ins at the moment, and I don't know how `$loggedInUser` is populated, but it should be a session variable, e.g. `$_SESSION['user']['id']`. That way you always know who the user is without having to send the data via a form; that is a real no-go.

Make sure to have `session_start()` at the top of each page, and ideally you'd use templates and you only have to add `session_start()` to the top of `index.php`.

And

```
$sql= "
INSERT INTO stories (author, author_id, story_name, story)
VALUES ('$author', '$author_id','$story_name', '$story')
";
```

Should at least be

```
$sql= "
INSERT INTO stories (author, author_id, story_name, story)
VALUES ('". $author ."', '". $author_id ."', '". $story_name ."', '". $story ."')
";
```

And I would personally recommend:

```
$q = "
INSERT INTO stories
        SET author_id = ". $_SESSION['user']['id'] ." # This is an integer (I assume) so don't use apostrophe's
          , story_name = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['story_name']) ."'
          , story = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['story']) ."'
";
```

Remove the field `author` from the table. Just use the `author_id` for table referencing, otherwise you're going to store duplicate data and when someone changes their author name, the author name in the stories is outdates/incorrect/obsolete.

Comment: Did this sort your issue? p.s. I see in your code that `mysql_close($con)` doesn't have a semi-colon at the end of the line. A semi-colon after the last line before PHP is close is optional, but will cause an error if you decide to add more code below :-)

Answer (score -1):

Check if the user is set, and just show that form if the user object is valid. Right before saving with mysql use the values from the user object instead of reading that from the POST-data.

```
<?php if ( isset($_POST['story_name']) ) {
// story posted.. check if user is set
if ( isset($loggedInUser->user_id) ) {
    // save into database using $loggedInUser->user_id and $loggedInUser->author_name
}
?>

<?php
// just show the form if the user object is set
if ( isset($loggedInUser->user_id) ){
?>
<form> <!-- and show the form over here --> </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Oh, and your `mysql_real_escape_string()` is good! another best practice is to add variables into your query using `sprintf()`:

```
$author     = mysql_real_escape_string($loggedInUser->author_name);
$author_id  = mysql_real_escape_string($loggedInUser->user_id);
$story_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['story_name']);
$story      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['story']);

$sql= sprintf("
INSERT INTO stories (author, author_id, story_name, story)
VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
", $author, $author_id, $story_name, $story); // %s accepts the value to be a string. %d accepts a decimal for example.
```

Comment: You shouldn't send userdata in requests, because it can be manipulated. Anyone can edit the hidden fields from the browser and post as someone else now..

Comment: You are right. Exactly what I rood at line 4 above, but not edited,in THE second codeblock.